# How to get this form path in Magento 2.0.4?

Tags: magento2, forms, discussion

> app/design/frontend/Venustheme/fasony/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/shipping.phtml`

Contains this code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php /** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping */ ?>

<div id="block-shipping" class="block shipping" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": true}}'>
    <div class="title" data-role="title">
        <strong id="block-shipping-heading" role="heading" aria-level="2">
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getQuote()->isVirtual() ? __('Estimate Tax') : __('Estimate Shipping and Tax') ?>
        </strong>
    </div>
    <div id="block-summary" data-bind="scope:'block-summary'" class="content" data-role="content" aria-labelledby="block-shipping-heading">
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
            {
                "#block-summary": {
                    "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>
                }
            }
        </script>
        <script>
            window.checkoutConfig = <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo \Zend_Json::encode($block->getCheckoutConfig()); ?>;
            window.customerData = window.checkoutConfig.customerData;
            window.isCustomerLoggedIn = window.checkoutConfig.isCustomerLoggedIn;
            require([
                'mage/url',
                'Magento_Ui/js/block-loader'
            ], function(url, blockLoader) {
                blockLoader("<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'); ?>");
                return url.setBaseUrl('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getBaseUrl();?>');
            })
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to know about is what is `$block->getJsLayout()`, what was the path for this layout ?

```
 <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <script type="text/x-magento-init">
                {
                    "#block-summary": {
                        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>
                    }
                }
            </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If we tried to view the Page Source, we will see a JSON layout.

Now, let's start to find where it comes.

*vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php*

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context, array $data = []){
    ......
    if (isset($data['jsLayout'])) {
            $this->jsLayout = $data['jsLayout'];
            unset($data['jsLayout']);
    }
    .....
}  


/**
 * Retrieve serialized JS layout configuration ready to use in template
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getJsLayout()
{
    return json_encode($this->jsLayout);
}
```

As we can see, the `$jsLayout` variable will be passed via `$data` array. It just applies the Dependence Injection concept to pass `jsLayout` to `$data` array. Now, take a look the layout xml. For example,

*vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml*

```
       <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
       ......
```

Sum up, the `getJsLayout()` will get the data from xml layout.